# Magento calling new defined model fails

Tags: magento, orm, model

I'm trying to create a new model within a Magento Plugin and even though I followed by letter a few tutorials, it doesn't seem to work:

Under **app/code/local/O2/OCustomer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <O2_OCustomer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </O2_OCustomer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <o2_ocustomer>
                <class>O2_OCustomer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>o2_ocustomer_resource</resourceModel>
            </o2_ocustomer>
            <o2_ocustomer_resource>
                <class>O2_OCustomer_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>customer_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <customer_group_website>
                        <table>o2_ocustomer_group_website</table>
                    </customer_group_website>
                </entities>
            </o2_ocustomer_resource>
        </models>
```

Under **app/code/local/O2/Ocustomer/Model/Customer/Group/Website.php**

```
<?php

class O2_OCustomer_Model_Customer_Group_Website extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_init('o2_ocustomer/customer_group_website');
    }
}
```

Under **app/code/local/O2/Ocustomer/Model/Resource/Customer/Group/Website.php**

```
<?php

class O2_OCustomer_Model_Resource_Customer_Group_Website extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_init('o2_ocustomer/customer_group_website', 'customer_group_website_id');
    }
}
```

I've tried both these calls, but none of them are working:

```
<?php
$model = Mage::getModel('ocustomer/customer_group_website');
var_dump(get_class($model));

$model = Mage::getModel('o2_ocustomer/customer_group_website');
var_dump(get_class($model));
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm stuck with this for more than a day and it's not right...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed it... Sorry for bothering. Finally saw that a class was badly named.

Comment: add the file that caused this problem along with this answer and then accept it.